# How to store data in couchbase through android app permanently

Tags: android, couchbase, couchbase-lite

I am new to android app development I am creating an app which creates a database called couchbase.
If I close my app, data stored in database is lost.
how can I create the database so that data remains even after closing the app.
Also I cannot find the database file. please tell where it is saved

I followed this tutorial:
https://acadgild.com/blog/working-with-couchbase-database-in-android-apps/

Comment: share your code.

Comment: can you please tell the location of .cblite file on android device?

Comment: `data stored in database is lost` you are misusing the database obviously.(using it incorrectly). Show how you do that, and only after that we can try to help.

Comment: The Github link in the tutorial is wrong.  Try https://github.com/hiteshbpatel/Android_Blog_Projects/tree/master/CouchbaseDatabaseExampleAndroid instead.

Answer (score 0):

> Also I cannot find the database file. please tell where it is saved

Which version of Couchbase Lite are you using ?

- In 1.4, you can use the [getDirectory()](https://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/mobile/1.5/references/couchbase-lite/couchbase-lite/manager/manager/index.html) method on CBLManager to get the location where the DB is stored
- In 2.0, you can look up the Directory property on [DatabaseConfiguration](https://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/mobile/2.0/guides/couchbase-lite/native-api/database/index.html?language=java)

And you may want to check sample Android apps on GitHub (https://github.com/couchbaselabs)  on how to get started with Couchbase Lite.

As mentioned by others, without any code describing what you are attempting to do, it's not feasible to determine what may be going on.

Comment: Thanks. I have shared the link of the tutorial i have exactly followed. Created the manager object , then created database and inserted the document. Can you please open the link and check.